# Modify active tab class bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style the active tab class, but doesn't seem to be working. The background always appear white.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
   <li class="active" id="id1" style="background-color: #234;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test1">test1</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="id2" href="#test2">test2</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
  #id1.active {
      background-color: #123 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Also, tried `li > .active`, `li.active`, `nav-tabs > li > .active` but none of them seem to be working.

**Never Mind**: The background was appearing white not because of the `li` element but the `a` element within it. I am suppose to modify the styling for `a`. Did this: `.active > a {..}`

Comment: Yes!! here comes the SO police to downvote and put questions behind bar !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to search for the `.nav-tabs` class inside the Bootstrap's CSS file and scroll down to the line where there's the `.active` class state, what you'll find is `.nav-tabs > li.active > a`, then that's the right place to edit its background.

> NOTE: The :hover and :focus state are also sharing the same style as
>   the normal active tab. You can also separate those two and give a
>   different `background-color` style.

And if you're going to style the `background-color` of `ul li.active {}` the result will be the default CSS list (including all other classes like `.nav-pills`, `.navbar-nav`, etc) that has the `.active` class state will have the same background color which is not appropriate.

So your CSS will then be:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  background-color /*here goes your background color*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `#id1 .active {}` it means you select an element of class `active` inside an element of id `#id1`. Instead you want just the active `<li>`:

```
ul li.active {
    background-color: #123 !important;
}
```

Explanation for your other tries:

- `li > .active` means a direct child element with class `active` of a `<li>`
- `li .active` means a child element with class `active` of a `<li>`
- `.nav-tabs > li > .active` the same as the first one, but the `<li>` is the direct child of an element of class `.nav-tabs`

[Here is a list](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) of possible CSS selectors and their meaning.

Comment: Even I don't understand, why do people downvote. Upvoted !! Thank you for your time and answer